# vitejs react override ant design less variables

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less, antd, tailwind-css

hope all good with you.

currently I am working on a new project configuration, I want to use vitejs, antdesign and tailwind , I am using [Vite.js](https://vitejs.dev/) react template as I mentioned then I've installed ant design using this command
`npm install antd`. Then I added these 3 lines in my `app.jsx`

```js
+ import { DatePicker } from "antd";
+ import "antd/dist/antd.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
+       <DatePicker />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and it worked properly, all I want to do now is to change the color theme less variables, I tried searching for modifyvars for vitejs but I failed, also I followed their docs but with vite i don't have webpack configuration file, it only worked with create-react-app template but not tailwind though. hope anyone can help and would i face any more problems if I installed tailwind after that.